# i want to submit a form but before submit i want to take a value from modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I want to submit a form but before submit i want to take a value from modal form . Actual requirement is that, i have to select multiple rows using checkbox and then i want to update database value.

```js
// <!-- JAVASCRIPT ON MODAL FORM SUBMIT -->
function changeLeadStage() {
  if (confirm("Are you sure want to UPDATE lead ?")) {
    document.frmUser.action = './changeleads.php';
    document.frmUser.submit();
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- BUTTON PRESSED AFTER SELECTING ROWS -->

<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success warning_1" value="changeLeadStage" onClick="action/changeLeadStage();" />

<!-- MODAL FORM -->
for updating the database after selecting rows i opened a model form and want to take a value from dropdown of form. and after submit i want to change database value.


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form name="frmUser" action="" method="POST">

          <select name="leadStageName" type="text" style="padding:5px; border-radius:3px;" required />
          <option value="" selected>Select LeadStage</option>
          <option value="LeadStage1">LeadStage1</option>
          <option value="LeadStage2">LeadStage2</option>
          <option value="LeadStage3">LeadStage3</option>
          <option value="LeadStage4">LeadStage4</option>
          <option value="LeadStage5">LeadStage5</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="changeLeadStage" class="btn btn-sm btn-success warning_1" onClick="action/changeLeadStage();" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You can try to add a `button` instead of `input[type=submit]` and on click of this button, validate form, show modal and get values. And on click of button on modal, submit the form.

Comment: If you want to use checkbox than use checkbox, html above shows select tag with options being used instead of checkboxes.

Comment: Also, change `onClick="action/changeLeadStage()"` to `onClick="changeLeadStage();"`

Answer (score 0):

Try some thing like this:

```
Change the input[type=submit] to input[type=button]
```

now on button click:

```
$('button').click(function(){
var value = $('#id').val();

// submit the form
$('#fomrid').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below snippet. I have made change in your code as per your requirement.

```js
function ChangeLeadStage() {  
  if (confirm("Are you sure want to UPDATE lead ?")) {
    var leadStageName = $("select[name='leadStageName']").val();
    alert(leadStageName);
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- BUTTON PRESSED AFTER SELECTING ROWS -->

<!-- MODAL FORM -->
for updating the database after selecting rows i opened a model form and want to take a value from dropdown of form. and after submit i want to change database value.


<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
  
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <form id="frmUser" name="frmUser" action="./changeleads.php" method="post" onsubmit="return ChangeLeadStage();">

          <select name="leadStageName" type="text" style="padding:5px; border-radius:3px;">
          <option value="" selected>Select LeadStage</option>
          <option value="LeadStage1">LeadStage1</option>
          <option value="LeadStage2">LeadStage2</option>
          <option value="LeadStage3">LeadStage3</option>
          <option value="LeadStage4">LeadStage4</option>
          <option value="LeadStage5">LeadStage5</option>
          </select>
          <br>
          <br>
          <br>
          <input type="submit" name="changeLeadStage" class="btn btn-sm btn-success warning_1" />
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```